# Apache Configuring options for sub file type

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm aware that you can configure by file type (first line below) but i'd like to be more specific.   I tired the 2nd line below, but didn't seem to work.   Am I doing something wrong?

```
#AddHandler server-parsed .html
# Would like to only parse *.dyn.js, instead of all *.js files 
AddHandler server-parsed .dyn.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not how you should do it. Here's why: according to the [mod_mime documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#multipleext), apache treats the all of the sections of the filename which begin with dot as an extension. In the example you provided, if you have a file, say, default.dyn.html, it is treated as a .dyn *and* as a .html file simultaneously. If simultaneous handling happens to be impossible, apache processes the extensions from right to left. So, you can't define an "extension" which contains a dot.

What you should do instead, it to define the "server-parsed" handler for the .dyn extension only. In this way, if you have a .dyn.html file, it will be registered to the server-parsed *handler* and to the text/html *mimetype*. Since these can coexist nicely, the file will be parsed, and will be served as an html page.